# Default value for models.GenericIpAddressField

Tags: python, django

i am trying to add another column in my model:

> ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField()

and when i run makemigrations, i have to set a default value. what should i put? thanks in advance.

**models.py**

```
class Prospect(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(VendicsUser, null=True)
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.full_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

either from shell when asked about default, you can enter any default ip for all the rows that are there, like 192.168.0.1 or you can change it in the model by putting an default value like

```
ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(default='192.168.0.1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(default='192.0.2.30')
```